# In Google Apps Script, how can I preserve newlines from user input?

Tags: google-apps-script, return, newline

I have a TextArea() that I'm collecting user input from.

I'd like to spit this input back out into an email, but it's important to preserve the formatting.  If someone puts in returns or paragraphs to separate their statements, I want that to be reflected in the output.

Currently, I have this input assigned to a variable, and then I reference the variable in the MailApp() call.  It is not preserving formatting through this process:

```
var user_input=e.parameter.text_area_input;

MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "someemail@somedomain.com",
  subject: "This is a subject.",
  htmlBody: "Here is the text that was entered: <BR>" + user_input
})
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Apparently HTML strips a lot of formatting - including sections of the strings that have more than one space - it reduces them to 1.  The issue here is that I was using htmlBody instead of just regular "body" to send my text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are sending a html email so you need to replace new line characters '\n' with line breaks <BR>.

Here are the options

```
//Send as text email
MailApp.sendEmail('someemail@somedomain.com',  
                   'This is a subject', 
                   'Here is the text that was entered: \n' + user_input);

//send as html email
MailApp.sendEmail('someemail@somedomain.com',  
                   'This is a subject', 
                   '', {htmlBody: 'Here is the text that was entered: <br>' + user_input.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')});
```

I have not tested the code. It may have syntax error or typo.

Comment: That worked beautifully.

I recognize the syntax you used in the .replace call as something from sed or awk in linux - is that accurate?

Comment: @user2308300 Yeah, those are regular expressions and almost work with every language with very or no modification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n` to do it, in `JavaScript`, `\n` means `n`