# How Can Line Breaks in Google Spreadsheets be Preserved When Posting to Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I have a script on Google app script. This script find a data simply.

my code :

```
var content=this.spreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange("C1:C26").getValues();
this.summary = contents[4][0];
```

I find my data , no prob but , my data has line breaks and my webpage on Google sites shows the result without line breaks.

It's a prob of convert with GetValue () ?

---

my data on a Cell of Spreadsheet :

```
blabab---
bla
abla---

bla
```

---

the result on a Google Site

`blabab---bla abla---bla`

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? You say "my data doesn't have *break_line* and my webpage on Google sites show the result without *break_line*". If that is what is happening, what is the problem? Also, by *break_line* do you mean a **line break** as in `\n`?

Comment: Yes ,in my cell of spreadsheet i have many line Break and on my WebPage on Google sites , i don't have one line break or /n or <br />  yes

Answer (score 4):

The solution is the following:

1. Get your string (in the cell) that you want to post to your Google Site.
2. Replace all line breaks (`\n`) in the string with the HTML version (`<br />`)

Something like the following:

```
function lineBreakTest() {
  var cellWithLineBreaks = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").getValue();
  Logger.log(cellWithLineBreaks);

  cellWithLineBreaks = cellWithLineBreaks.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

  Logger.log(cellWithLineBreaks);

  // Post to your Google Site here. Logger.log is just used to demonstrate.

}
```

The reason you have to do this is because Spreadsheets uses normal text line breaks `\n` in its cells. However, Google sites uses HTML format, so you need to do the 'conversion'. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208927/in-google-apps-script-how-can-i-preserve-newlines-from-user-input) is also a helpful source.

Comment: Thanks Chris but ,  in my Google sites i see  :  ( for example :  <br /><br /><br /><br />The main objective of this project is to ... <br /> )       This code is display on the page.html in the same Google script projet ( i use a textArea on the html page,   so the prob concerns the html page in google script   and not the cell on the spreadsheet ? )

Comment: You will need to use HTML Box, which is a "Gadget" in Google Sites, or use methods in the `Sites` class that use *HTML* as a parameter. See the [Sites class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/)

Comment: I can't use a gadget in my Google sites,  i have a template HTMl    test_data.html and  my String is in an object  TP  :
  My string :   TP.summary;

my code : 
<?= TP.summary  ?>
<? if(this.edit) {?>
</textarea><?}?>

i have remplace with you code Chris but , i see <br /> in string , not a break_line ...

Comment: Well to my knowledge Google Sites by default render HTML in posts, both `Announcements` and on `Pages`. You could try replacing with `<br>` instead of `<br />`, and that may do the trick. If your text is *not* being rendered as HTML, then you need to use `\n` as a delimiter for **line breaks**. `\r` is a carriage-return, which functions pretty much the same. You can try using that as well. However, if your text *is* being rendered as HTML, you need to use an HTML tag that gives you a *line break*. `<br>` and `<p>` are similar in my experience. Try one of those alternatives :)

Comment: As an additional note... since you're using the HTML `<textarea>` tag... you should see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581393/html-textarea-input-doesnt-recognize-line-breaks). Pretty much a direct answer to your question ;) at least... I think. Also see documentation on the [`textarea tag`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

Comment: Thx Chris but , the tag br don't working, i see the tag on my Google sites page  ,  but le tag p  i don't see the tag but no break line on my google sites page ... :(

Comment: the code  withe replace fonction:
`testtest</p><p>test</p><p></p><p>testtest`
The Google site page :
`</p><p>testtest</p><p>test</p><p></p><p>testtest`

it's the same with `<br>`

Comment: Well that means that your Google side is not rendering HTML, or you are not *setting* the HTML correctly. It's likely the latter. Look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/) to use the correct methods for creating `Announcements` or `Pages`. **Both** take HTML as a parameter, so if you use *those* methods properly, your HTML (`<br>`, `<p>` tags, etc.) will render as it should.